# How to show the completeness of the following subset of $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let's define the subset of $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$
$$\mathcal D(A) = \left\{ {z \in {\ell ^2}\left( C \right),\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k^2{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2} < \infty } } \right\},$$

I want to show the completeness of this subset.

my attempt:

We take a Cauchy sequence $\left\{ {z_{}^{\left( m \right)}} \right\}$ in $\mathcal{D}(A)$  and verify that the limit point is in $\mathcal{D}(A)$. Let
\begin{eqnarray}
{z_n} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } z_n^{\left( m \right)}
\end{eqnarray}
This implies component wise convergence, i.e,
$\left| {z_n^{\left( m \right)} - {z_n}} \right| \to 0$ since ${\left\| {z - {z^{(m)}}} \right\|_2} \to 0$ in the $\ell_2$ sense, i.e., convergence in the $\ell_2$ sense implies convergence component wise. However, since $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {z_k^{\left( m \right)}} \right|}^2}}  < \infty$ for all $m$ then it holds that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left| {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {{z_k}} \right|}^2}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{k^2}{{\left| {z_k^{\left( m \right)}} \right|}^2}} } \right| \to 0
\end{eqnarray}
as $m\to \infty$. The fact that $z$ is in $\ell^2$ is tivial since $\ell^2$ is a complete normed space (it is both Hilbert and Banach). Hence we showed that $z \in \mathcal D(A)$.

Are there any mistakes in my approach?

Comment: Without commenting on your proof, it might be simpler to show that ${\cal D}(A)$ is closed: closed subsets of complete spaces are complete.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that showing closedness might be equally hard.

Comment: @UmbertoP. How would I go about proving that?

Comment: The non-trivial part of what you have to verify is that the limit you wrote down actually tends to $0$. You need to justify it, because essentially it boils down to interchanging a limit and an infinite series.

Comment: I thought it is obvious since we have the limit component wise. Wait, let me get this right, you referring to the difference between the two infinite sums?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are not asking the question you'd really want to ask.

First, no, the closure of that set is the whole $\ell^2$, because it includes all finite linear combinations of standard basis elements.

But it might be (as in some real-life applications, e.g., Sobolev spaces) that you want to define a new norm by (the square root of) the expression that you wrote. This gives a new inner-product-space structure, and (as with $\ell^2$ itself) gives a complete space.